# Staging environment for multiple clients: subfolders or subdomains

Tags: php, laravel

*Disclaimer: This is not a strictly-programming question, but a general how-to one. I've been programming in Laravel for some time, so what I need is an advice on preparing the setup described below.*

**The idea**

I am planning to do some freelance web development and put Laravel at the heart of it. To do that, I would like to start with setting up a global staging for my future clients, so each of them can see their website progress at any time.

The idea I have is a "client hub" - central gate to individual stagings:

1. Client accesses example.com/client and logs in with provided
   credentials
2. On successful login, the client is redirected to their respective
   staging

**Question**

My initial thought was to keep each client in a single subfolder, with clean Laravel installation. Is it a good idea in terms of security/efficiency? What programming problems may this create?

Other idea is a subdomain for each client. Problem is, this means a vhost for every new Laravel installation, and every vhost equals costs.

What do you think? Subfolders or subdomains?

Answer (score 1):

Properly configured, there would be no difference. However you'd have to configure cookies and base url for every subfolder. Using subdomains would make setup quicker.

Comment: The ease of rolling out a fresh client staging is definitely something that speaks to me. Thanks for this one.